# Get CR_NO values for the same table in sql

Tags: sql

[image]

Some can help me on this query? I need this

Comment: I have edited the text. Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `exists` as follows:

```
Select cr_no, so, id
From your_table t
Where exists (select 1 from your_table tt
Where t.cr_no <> tt.cr_no
  And t.so = tt.so
  And t.id = tt.id)
```